# Rationalization in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm, floating-point

"The Joy of Clojure" says not to rationalize values that are Java float or double primitives.

Why not rationalize them but it is ok to rationalize instances of java.lang.Float and java.lang.Double?

[EDIT]
The book ([page 67](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/clojure/9781935182641/on-scalars/67)) doesn't suggest it is ok to rationalize java.lang.Float or java.lang.Double but it shows an example:

```
(def a (rationalize 1.0e50))
(def b (rationalize -1.0e50))
(def c (rationalize 17.0e00))
```

Comment: Where does it say that? Closest thing I can find is in section 4.2.3 where it says to be careful deciding when to do it, because its much slower than arithmetic on floats/doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, is there a difference between rationalizing a double v.s. a Double (or a float v.s. a Float)?  No, not really. You're going to end up with a Ratio object in either case, and you're going to have the same performance characteristics when doing lots of math on that type.

e.g.

```
user=> (class (rationalize 0.56))
clojure.lang.Ratio
user=> (class (Double. 0.56))
java.lang.Double
user=> (class (rationalize (Double. 0.56)))
clojure.lang.Ratio
```

Still though, if you need that sort of accuracy, then that would be the way to go. But if you can use standard computer floating point arithmetic, then you'll be better off because this will translate much more directly into machine instructions than working with Ratio objects will.

Answer (score 1):

If you rationalize primitive values you'll get objects instead of primitives, and this will dramatically slow down your computations (you'll need to perform boxing/unboxing plus object values consume [a lot more memory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html) than primitives due to meta information, for example `Int` will consume x4 memory than `int`).

`java.lang.Double` already have this overhead so there will not be a lot of difference.